# Scrollbar Overlay When Hover and Keep Position

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

So I am attempting to show the div scroll on hover without changing the width. So far with the code I have identified the following problems:

- When the scrollbar is removed after hover it goes back to the top **UPDATE:** **This is fixed by** `overflow-y:hidden`
- When you use overlay all images are on top of the scrollbar (still an issue)

Is there a better way of doing this or a way of fixing these issues in CSS? I am open to any JS plugins if there's an easier solution.

**Example:**

```css
.test{
  height:300px;
  max-height:100px;
  width:300px;
  max-width:310px;
}

.test:hover{
  overflow-y:overlay;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
<img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
</div>
```

Comment: For your second problem: `.test img {width: calc(100% - 16px); height: auto;}` -- the 16px is an estimate of the width of the scrollbar. Not sure about your first problem...

Comment: you don't even need the - width, if the image width is set it's not going to resize it

Comment: Not sure why I've been -1! A mystery.. Anyway I think I'm nearly there, not sure any solutions yet address the image over the scrollbar without keeping all elements less of a width or some combination.

Comment: I think this may be a browser specific issue, what browser are you using?

Comment: I use chrome.. overlay only works in Safari and Chrome (I believe) so it's ironic if it is a bug in the only browser that allows it.. think I'm going to have to go back to the drawing board and looks for js alternatives.

Comment: i do know of a solution that would work for this but it would involve JavaScript to accomplish.

Comment: @Wickey312 check my solution out, its not the full code but i think that is ruffly what you are looking to achieve here

Answer (score 2):

So I got it not to scroll to the top, with `hidden`.  It appears that `auto` (as the default overflow) forces it back up to the top.

So use `hidden` when it is not hovered.

Still a problem of images on the scroll bar.  (Need to retrieve the size of the scroll bar and add to the biggest img and set it to the size of the div.test)

```css
.test {
  height: 300px;
  inline-size: max-content;
}

.test img {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right:17px /*asuuming it is the normal size*/
}

.test:hover {
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

.test:not(:hover) {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300"><br/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" style="width:350px"><br/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300"><br/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300"><br/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Zekrom_Vale (I didn't -1).. I don't believe this fixes images overlaying on scroll?

Comment: hello, i'm from 2023 and your answer helped me 

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn't exactly what you are after but i have added it just to demonstrate what i think you are looking for.

```
    <div id="outer">
    <div id="top">
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>10th P Tag</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>20th P Tag</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>30th P Tag</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>10th P Tag</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>20th P Tag</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>Content Here</p>
        <p>30th P Tag</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#bottom').on('scroll', function () {
            $('#top').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        div {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;

}
#outer {
  width    : 50%;
  height   : 300px;
  overflow : hidden;
}
#top {
    overflow : hidden;
    left     : 0;
    background-color: blue;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 300px;
}
#bottom {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;  
    opacity: 0.5;
    left       : 0;
    overflow   : auto;
    overflow-x : hidden;
    overflow-y : hidden;
}
#bottom:hover{
     overflow-y:scroll;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I would avoid !important as it is almost impossible to remove it, also what if you have different sized images?

Comment: I'll set it to 100%, the important is a little redundant here but it does as the question describes